# Infix to Postfix Using Stacks - Java

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

I am trying to learn and implement some practical uses of stacks and I am doing a little program that takes in an equation and converts it to postfix notation. I am aware of how postfix notation, stacks and precedence works so the syntax approach I took seems to make sense to me however it seems to print it out in some sort of prefix notation with some duplicates at times, its really odd. Any help would be appreciated and I'll leave all of my code for you guys below, thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        infixToPostfix();
    }

    private static int Precedence(char character) {

        System.out.print("" + character);
        switch (character) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '/':
        case '*':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static String infixToPostfix() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<>();
        System.out.println("please enter your equation");
        String equation = scanner.nextLine();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < equation.length(); i++) {
            char ch = equation.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                result.append(ch);
            } else if (ch == '(') {
                operatorStack.push(ch);
            } else if (operatorStack.isEmpty()
                    && !Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                operatorStack.push(ch);
            } else {
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(ch)
                            && Precedence(
                                    ch) < operatorStack
                                            .peek()) {
                        result.append(operatorStack.pop());
                    } else if (!Character.isDigit(ch)
                            && Precedence(
                                    ch) > operatorStack
                                            .peek()) {
                        operatorStack.push(ch);
                    } else if (ch == ')') {
                        result.append(operatorStack.pop());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result.toString();
    }


}
```

```
2*(3+1) // input
++23(*1 // output
31+2* // expected output

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please [edit] your question and add an example input, the expected output and what you get instead?

Comment: Check out the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: Hey there thanks for your comment i have edited my code so that I have all those 3 things in at the bottom

Comment: I'll check it out now cheers!

Comment: You are comparing the precedence of the current operator with the operator on top of the stack, instead of iwith the *precedence* of the operator on top of the stack. Check your reference source.